# cannot access mysql database remotely on ubuntu

Tags: mysql

Here are the steps I followed for accessing the database remotely:

For machine A

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
sudo mysql_install_db
set bind_address=0.0.0.0 on path /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

started mysql database on machine A

```
mysql -u root -p
```

created a user using following command

```
create user 'techrocks'@'%' identified by 'myass';
grant all privileges on *.* to 'techrocks'@'%';
flush privileges;
```

exit mysql and restart mysql, then `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart`

ON machine B I installed mysql-server and then tried to access mysql of machine A

```
mysql -u techrocks -h ip-address-of-machine-A -p
```

mysql started but when I tried to create a database as

```
create database mydb1;
```

I got access denied error

```
Access denied for user 'teckrocks'@'%' to database 'mydb1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Open my.cnf (/etc/mysql/my.cnf) 
bind = IP of remote

then try to connect..

Comment: but by this solution i will be able to access mysql from 1 machine only. How can i access mysql from machine c, d ,e
i actually want general solution for the above problem

Comment: Our MySQL service is bound to serve localhost only (interface binding). This is the default for security reasons. You will need to change it for other machines manually.

Comment: i didnt got you exactly but i guess you are trying to say that i need to add ip-address of remote machine in server machine like
bind-address=ip-of-machine-a
bind-address=ip-of-machine-c
likewise